# How do I have one OpenWRT router use the DHCP server of another OpenWRT router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, openwrt

I want one router to be able to access the devices connected to the other router. However one router is connected to the internet modem by ethernet, and the other router is connected to it by wireless AC. Devices connected to both can connect to the internet.

My issue is similar to this: [Static routing on a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND](https://superuser.com/questions/358818/static-routing-on-a-tp-link-tl-wr1043nd?lq=1)

But I do not understand how to do it using OpenWRT using the features of OpenWRT. There are several questions covering this, but they are very general, and I'm a bit lost on this matter as I don't understand the specific settings for OpenWRT I need to adjust.

I would prefer it if the settings to alter could be done through Luci.

Comment: You want a wireless Bridge?

Comment: @Xen2050 I think so, but I thought that's why I already have going since packets do reach the internet.